# Regex for removing of empty paragraphs

Tags: c#, regex, replace, paragraph

I need to remove empty paragraph elements.

```
<p id="abc"></p>
<p id="cde">Text<br/>More text</p>

text = Regex.Replace(text, @"<p(.*?)></p>", "");
```

My regex removes the first and the second paragraph, I need to remove just the first one.

Comment: Here I need to use regex.

Comment: Your regex works perfectly - https://dotnetfiddle.net/CulhZw.

Answer (score 4):

```
<p.*?><\/p>
```

You can check here https://regex101.com/r/nH8tB2/2

C# working sample: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6sb3VY

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var str = @"<p id=""abc""></p>
<p id=""cde"">Text<br/>More text</p>";
        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(str, @"<p.*?><\/p>", ""));
    }
}
```

Comment: @anubhava He added in another element like the first one. It is absolutely OK.

Comment: @anubhava yeah, I added another empty `<p>` to show the regex working